# Why can't I query this range?

Tags: c#, linq

Yet again, I've come up against a LINQ issue I don't understand.

So I thought I'd better ask a generic question so maybe next time I can figure it out for myself.

What is wrong with this statement?

```
var cells = settingsSheet.Range["B1:B999"].Select(x => x.Value2 != null);
```

Forget the fact that it's an Excel range, I want to know why I can't just query it in this way.
Thinking it might be a Type issue I've tried the following and this doesn't work either:

```
var cells = settingsSheet.Range["B1:B999"].ToList<Excel.Range>().Select(x => x.Value2 != null);
```

When I say doesn't work, the word Value2 appears in red ("Cannot resolve symbol Value2").

Value2 is a valid property of the Range class.

Why can't I do it this way?

To clarify, the following works fine:

```
var cells = settingsSheet.Range["B1:B999"];
foreach (var q in cells)
{
   a = q.Value2);
}
```

Comment: I suspect you'll find there's an error message. What is that error message? Note that in the first case, you've got a *single* range and you're asking for the `Value2` for each element within the range. In your second case, you're creating a `List<Range>` and asking for the `Value2` of each range - not each element within each range.

Comment: What is the type of `settingsSheet`?

Comment: Fair enough, although I was clutching at straws there. Error message added ("Cannot resolve symbol Value2").

Comment: settingsSheet is an Excel.Worksheet

Comment: I think the fact that it is an Excel.Range that is the problem. Whatever it contains does not have a Value2 property.

Comment: My thinking also, except the Range class does have a Value2 property. I'm thinking there may be an implicit casting going on I'm not aware of - - ?

Comment: Range[X] returns SINGLE Range instance which itself is IEnumerable (of Objects). It does not return multiple "Range"s.

Comment: Not quite true; if you Enumerate a Range, you get Range objects

Comment: No, when you enumerate a Range you get List of Objects. Not List of Ranges. I'm not experienced with Office interop so I can't tell you what exactly is inside said list.

Comment: But those objects have a Value2 property. See my update...

Comment: I fixed it; it seems that `settingsSheet` was not strongly typed enough - simple as that! (Darned Resharper)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I had strongly-typed my settingsSheet variable, this is what worked:

```
var cells = settingsSheet.Range["B1:B999"].Cast<Excel.Range>().Select(x => x.Value2 != null);
```

So, the result of `Range[]` must be explicitly cast to a `Range` type.

Although there is a push towards implicit typing, explicit typing is needed for querying with LINQ